# Binding a TextBlock to the .NextSibling of a ComboBox Value

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a ComboBox that is currently bound to an XML file:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="employeeNameBox" IsReadOnly="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" IsEditable="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource People}, XPath=./Person/personName}" Text="Select Employee"/>
```

The employee names populate inside the combobox correctly.  The next step I have is trying to bind a TextBlock to one of the sibling node of the selected employee name:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="employeeEmail" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=employeeNameBox,Path=SelectedValue}" Text="{Binding XPath=./Person/personEmail}" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,5,0,0" MinWidth="120"/>
```

Here is the structure of the XML file:

```
<Person>
    <personName>John Doe</personName>
    <personEmail>someone@yahoo.com</personEmail>
    <personReports>Their reports here</personReports>
</Person>
```

Based on the personName selected by the ComboBox, I an trying to get the TextBlock to auto fill in the corresponding personEmail.  For extra credit, the next step I will have is alos populating the personReports into a ListBox:

```
<ListBox Height="100" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,5,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=employeeNameBox,Path=SelectedItem.personReports}"/>
```

I apprecite the help guys, still learning all the nuances to data binding a WPF.

Thanks!

Comment: Unless you are building a view/application to view any XML file (even if it didn't have Person elements) it would be easier and more rewarding to instead create a model/class for your Person records/elements and just bind to your class' properties. Thus, you separate your data (XML file) from your View (XAML).

Comment: So in this instance could I bind directly to the Constructor class for the Person Object?  i.e. Class NewPerson contains all the elements of Person, and the XML is just a collection of those objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `SelectedValue` contains string of currently selected item and you can't use XPath with string as `DataContext`.

Try to bind `DataContext` to `SelectedItem` instead of `SelectedValue`. Then you can use following XPath to get following sibling element :

```
<TextBlock DataContext="{Binding ElementName=employeeNameBox, Path=SelectedItem}" 
            Text="{Binding XPath=./following-sibling::personEmail}"/>
```